# SPO / Modern Pages - Saved drafts not accessible / visible to owners/editors

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, modern-pages, draft, sharepoint-news

Has anyone encountered the issue with saved drafts of modern pages not being accessible/visible to those in the owners and editors groups, or even other site collection administrators?

The documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/management-and-lifecycle-of-a-sharepoint-modern-page-3410a04c-3ca4-4a4c-b867-33ab5c8bdcf3) states that:

> Save as draft - When you save and close this page, it is checked in as a minor version, and becomes a "shared" draft. This means that anyone with edit permissions (or site owners) can now see it and edit it.

But this doesn't seem to be the case.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also not able to see the draft site page in SharePoint Online. I can only see that someone else is editing this page, at top right corner of page like given below:

[image]

However, someone else has raised same concern on SharePoint UserVoice. You can vote using below URL:

[Overview of published pages vs drafts](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/33466771-overview-of-published-pages-vs-drafts).